# Python logging termination

Tags: python, exception, logging, raise

## The problem

What is the best way to deal with situation that I want to log an exception to console, file, etc. and then terminate the program?
Suppose I read in a config and validate whether the entries given make sense. If not, I want to raise an InvalidConfigError, log this error and terminate since there is no way to recover from this.

## What I've done

```
try:
    config = validate_config(read_config(cfg_file_path))
except InvalidConfigError:
    logging.getLogger(__name__).exception(f'Config validation failed.')
    exit(1)
```

## Thoughts

When I do (notice `raise`)

```
try:
    config = validate_config(read_config(cfg_file_path))
except InvalidConfigError:
    logging.getLogger(__name__).exception(f'Config validation failed.')
    raise
```

I will get duplicated tracebacks in my console log since I log the whole thing incl. the traceback in my exception logging call and then raise it again which will print the whole thing again.

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like exit(1) is not particularly nice.

## My logging config

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False
formatters:
  simple:
    format: "%(asctime)s : %(name)-12s : %(levelname)-10s %(message)s"

handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout

  info_file_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: simple
    filename: data/logs/info.log
    maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
    backupCount: 5
    encoding: utf8

  error_file_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level: ERROR
    formatter: simple
    filename: data/logs/errors.log
    maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
    backupCount: 5
    encoding: utf8

root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console, info_file_handler, error_file_handler]
```

Comment: `sys.exit()` is preferred over `exit()` in non-interactive python.